# Is it possible to configure Two different authentication mechanism for Service fabric RestFull Service APIs

Tags: jwt, azure-service-fabric, restful-authentication

Is it possible for my Azure service fabric Stateless service to have two type of authentication?

I have two APIs in my service

One is to create the "XYZ" resource. Ideally called by mobile application with Json Web Token.

another one is to retrieve all the created resources which would be called by another cloud service by providing a custom Authorization token.

Could any one help me to understand, is this workflow possible ?. If so, What would be the ideal way to implement the Authorization logic.

Answer (score 0):

You would do this via two different communication listeners, usually, where each would implement proper handling of the credential type that was being presented.